# Running sequential commands through ssh on multiple servers

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I have a list of servers in a file that I pass to the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

    ssh_cmd="user@$line"
    ssh $ssh_cmd 'hostname && ls -l /path/to/folder | grep some_token' &

done < "$1"
```

What I want is output like this:

```
  output from hostname (1)
  output from ls -l (1)
  output from hostname (2)
  output from ls -l (2)
  output from hostname (3)
  output from ls -l (3)
```

But these seem to be mixed up:

```
  output from ls -l (1)
  output from hostname (1)      
  output from hostname (2)
  output from ls -l (2)
  output from ls -l (3)
  output from hostname (3)
```

Is there some way to ensure that these commands happen sequentially?

Thanks in adv!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` at the end of this line makes it so the process runs in the background:

```
ssh $ssh_cmd 'hostname && ls -l /path/to/folder | grep some_token' &
```

If you remove the `&` from that line, the script will wait until the ssh session finishes to continue on to the next iteration of the loop. Also, you will need to add the `-n` flag to the ssh command so that it doesn't read from stdin. This will give you the sequential output you're looking for.

Final command:

```
ssh -n $ssh_cmd 'hostname && ls -l /path/to/folder | grep some_token'
```

Comment: Thanks. When I remove the trailing `&` the script only executed for the 1st item in the list. Is `ssh` somehow eating the rest of the input?

Comment: The reason my loop wasn't completing was that ssh was eating up the rest of the stdin stream. This was fixes by adding the `-n` flag to my `ssh` command: `ssh -n user@server command1 && command2`

Comment: @PatMustard Great! Sorry I didn't think of that, glad you got it fixed! I'll edit it into my answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GNU Parallel` to do them all nicely in parallel and use the `-k` option to keep the output in order:

```
parallel -k -a hosts.txt 'echo ssh user@{} "hostname; ls"'
```

So, if `hosts.txt` contains the following:

```
host1
host27
host32
host100
hostfreddyfrog
hostmichaelfish
```

you will get this:

```
ssh user@host1 hostname; ls
ssh user@host27 hostname; ls
ssh user@host32 hostname; ls
ssh user@host100 hostname; ls
ssh user@hostfreddyfrog hostname; ls
ssh user@hostmichaelfish hostname; ls
```

Obvioulsy you need to remove the `echo` and add in your quoting and gripping, but the concept should be clear enough.

Another advantage, other than it now being a one-liner, is that if you have 32,000 hosts to work on, `GNU Parallel` can be told, using the `-j` flag, how many processes to run at a time without overloading your server. By default, if you have 8 cores in your CPU, it will run 8 jobs in parallel, but you could set it to 64 for example with

```
parallel -k -j 64 ...
```

You can also set up `GNU Parallel` to be able to `ssh` into hosts itself, normally in order to distribute processing jobs amongst servers, then the job becomes even easier.

```
parallel -S node1,node4,node56 'hostname; grep ...'
```

See [example here.](http://deepdish.io/2014/09/15/gnu-parallel/)

ALternative syntaxes for passing `hosts.txt` are

```
parallel -k 'echo ssh user@{} "hostname; ls"' < hosts.txt
```

or

```
parallel -k 'echo ssh user@{} "hostname; ls"' :::: hosts.txt
```